# What is the API used in Google Chrome's embedded PDF Viewer?

Tags: api, google-chrome, pdf

I want to make some modifications to the Google Chrome extension which lets us view PDf documents, do you know whether Google Chrome API lets us do it?

**Update** the API used is PDFium (https://opensource.google/projects/pdfium).
Used in Chrome for displaying PDFs and print preview.

Comment: @bummi I do not see where am I asking for a recommendation here. I was only asking which one is the SDK used by Google Chrome in its own implementation. Which is PDFium. This is different to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial...", as my question only allows for a unique possible answer: PDFium.

Comment: TL;DR: The answer is PDFium (https://opensource.google/projects/pdfium).
Used in Chrome for displaying PDFs and print preview.

Answer (score 0):

Just embed the pdf, and it will be integrated!

```
<embed name="plugin" type="application/pdf"
   width="100%" height="100%" 
   src="http://mysite.com/somefile.pdf" />
```

Comment: I want to do modifications in the Viewing Plugin, not just being able to watch the PDF files in Google Chrome.

Comment: I've got the same wishes, I'm assuming there is no api to do this, is that correct? for instance being able to scroll the pdf to a certain point and simple things like that? as far as I can tell that's not supported.

Comment: TL;DR: The answer is PDFium (https://opensource.google/projects/pdfium).
Used in Chrome for displaying PDFs and print preview.